# How to disable(inactive) a div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to javascript, can any one please help me.

Actually I have a div in my html, I would like to disable the div on page loading. the code is

```
<div class="col-1" id="plug_play_box" >
    <div class="box first">
        <div class="pad">
            <div class="wrapper indent-bot">
                <strong class="numb img-indent2">01</strong>
                <div class="extra-wrap">
                    <h3 class="color-1">
                        <strong>Plug </strong><label id="and">&</label> Play
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <a class="button img-indent-r" href="#" id="plug_play_button"></a>
                <div class="extra-wrap">
                    Point.co is one of free website templates created by TemplateMonster.com.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: Disable a Div? Div's are by default read-only.. please improve question..

Comment: what do you mean by disable the div ?

Comment: give your div an id `<div id="some_div">`, and use `document.getElementById('some_div').style.display='none';`, this will hide the div, you can't disable a div

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable a DIV, only inputs.

You can hide a DIV however, using jQuery it would be done like MichelRobico suggested, however if you aren't using jQuery it would be :

```
document.getElementById(Your_Div_Id).hidden = true;
```

Or you could use :

```
var divs_to_hide=document.getElementsByClassName(Your_Div_Class);
for (var i=0;i<divs_to_hide.length;i++)
{
    divs_to_hide[i].hidden=true;
}
```

and iterate through the resultant array to hide them individually. However, if you're new I'd stick to using ID's.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName(Your_Div_Class).hidden = true;` this won't work, getElementByClassName returns an array, so you have to loop through the array to hide a div

Comment: Does it? My bad! Don't normally use getElementsByClassName() so I didn't realise, although looking at the function name I can see that now. I'll edit my response appropriately, thank you.

Comment: as you can see it is getElementsByClassName notice the `S` at the end of element

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what do you mean by disable div.

To modify div on page loading you can do:

`jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#plug_play_box').hide();
});`

In this example I've hide the div, but you can apply any other modification

Comment: he's new to javascript, you're giving him jquery stuff that won't work unless he has jquery... Explain more, or use pure JS

Answer (score -2):

```
 $(function () {
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#plug_play_box").hide();  // Use this for hiding div by Id   
       $(".col-1").hide();   // Use this for hiding div by class
     });
 });
```

Comment: he's new to javascript, you're giving him jquery stuff that won't work unless he has jquery... Explain more, or use pure JS